# Server asks for Username and Password when Uploading File

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

To Upload a File, I added `<identity impersonate="true" />` to the `Web.Config` file because I could not set READ and WRITE permissions.

And everything worked perfectly, but now, and I don't know the reason, the server keeps asking me for a username and a password to upload a file, and I insert my ftp username and password.

How can I bypass this? (I can only edit Web.config)

Currently, I have this:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />

<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

I tried:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="ftpaccount" password="ftppassword" />
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Which IIS version your server uses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option tried by you seems little incorrect since while using WindowsAuthentication, UserNames should be of Form: `DOMAIN_NAME\UserName` for domain accounts and `COMPUTER_NAME\UserName` for local user account.

Also make sure the User Account being tried to impersonate has the sufficient privileges to create files in your upload directories. This was one reason why my application also faced same situation while using: `<identity impersonate="true" />`

Below concise description may be of some help.

When using IIS 7.5, The ASP.NET application uses Network Service account to make request for System resources.
This setting is defined in `<processModel>` element of `<system.web>` section of `Machine.config` .

```
<processModel autoConfig="true" />
```

In some cases  the value for `autoConfig`  can be false. So two ways possible when using Windows authentication: [ Supply these in Web.config of your applicaion ]

1.) `<identity impersonate="true" />`.  we should make sure that the user whose identity is being
     impersonated has sufficient rights for creating files in the Upload directories.

2.) We can supply an account name that will always be used :

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="DOMAIN\Username" password="password" />
```

Again user needs to have sufficient privileges. Also make sure UserName is of format:  `DOMAIN_NAME\UserName` for domain accounts and `COMPUTER_NAME\UserName` for local user account.

Comment: Using `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;` I got a name in the format you specified, so now, this is the default user that is being impersonated right? All I have to allow this user READ/WRITE access to the folder that I'm uploading to?

Comment: Also, when I removed impersonate = true, I got this : `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.

Comment: YESS. Correct. So now, did you tried by giving sufficient privileges to the user account ? OR try using an UserAccount that already has sufficient privileges.

Comment: I don't have access to the IIS Server, I have to contact the most person I hate right now in this world.